# How to create an object once and use it several times in Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to populate an object using methods in a Controller class. So I've created the object in the Controller class and then tried to populate it using methods in the class. This does not work though, because everytime a method in a controller is called, the entire Controller class is reinitiated. So I get a brand new object everytime I try to populate the object. However, I don't know how else I can create an object and populate it. I've added the code below. The object I'm talking about is `ProcessModel`. Ignore the other objects I created at the top of the class.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ProcessModel pm = new ProcessModel();
    RetrievePatterns pt = new RetrievePatterns();
    RetrieveModel rm = new RetrieveModel();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        FindPatterns fp = new FindPatterns(rm.pm, pt.KpiPatterns);
        ViewData["KPIs"] = fp.passdata;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddEvent([FromBody] Event data)
    {
        data.ID = pm.EventObjects.Count + 1;
        pm.EventObjects.Add(data);
        return Json(pm.EventObjects.Count);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddProcessName(string data)
    {
        pm.ID = 1;
        pm.Name = data;
        return Json(new { title = pm.Name });
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

Object:

```
public class ProcessModel
{
    public List<Event> EventObjects = new List<Event>();
    public List<Entity> EntityObjects = new List<Entity>();
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Singleton` class which is responsible to create only one instance from `Process` model;

```
public class ProcessModelSingleton
{
    private static ProcessModel _processModel = new ProcessModel();

    private ProcessModelSingleton()
    {

    }

    public static ProcessModel Instance
    {
        get { return _processModel; }
    }
}
```

Then assign it a global variable in the controller;

```
ProcessModel pm = ProcessModelSingleton.Instance;
```

**EDIT**

Created instance by singleton class shared by all users. So, if you want to make it user specific, using `Session` is the best option.

```
public ProcessModel pm {
    get
    {
        if (Session["ProcessModel"] == null)
        {
            Session["ProcessModel"] = new ProcessModel();
        }
        return (ProcessModel)Session["ProcessModel"];
    }  
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: This means that *all* users of your site will fill this *single* object. It is far better to store it in (user specific) Session

Comment: The user didn't provide any details about user specific. Otherwise of course Session is the best option.

Comment: @Rainman - true, nothing was specified. But in at least 99% of cases it should be user specific. And in most of the remaining cases "tab specific" is wanted

Comment: @HansKesting Very good point. For now, this is the right solution. In the future I will have to switch to sessions. I hope the other answer below will be sufficient for me to implement sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind static variables are shared across all users for that web server. So data populated into a singleton class by one user's request can be read/overwritten by a different user's request. This may be what you are after, but if not you should look into Session State.

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

As HTTP is stateless by nature, usage of sessions are discouraged my Microsoft for Asp.NET. By default they are only visible to the web server that creates them so if you are using a farm, you either need to look at server affinity (also called sticky sessions) with a load balancer or out of proc state (such as SQL Server or NCache).

Ideally your application design should avoid the need for sessions and carry only the necessary data between requests via cookies and/or query strings. For more complex applications however this is usually not possible and so Session State is used.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. For now, the singleton pattern is sufficient. In the future I'll have to make use of sessions. I hope the link you provided will guide me in that.